# Xubuntu 16.04.6 freezes

Tags: xubuntu

I have installed a fresh Xubuntu 16.04.6 on an Asus p5e motherboard, and I periodically get a freeze. Alt+F2 doesn't work either.

videocard is Asus en8600 gt
memory is Samsung ddr2-400 8 Gb
swap is off
memtest from system is ok

In syslog i see only (after restart)

```
Feb 19 14:17:01 natalyp5e CRON[9172]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 19 15:17:01 natalyp5e CRON[10299]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e dbus[789]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e dbus[789]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3658]: ** (gvfsd:3743): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to retrieve share list from     server: Connection refused
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3658]: ** (process:10308): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified     location is not mounted
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3658]: ** (process:4000): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/ enumerator/1 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3658]: message repeated 14 times: [ ** (process:4000): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/1 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)]
Feb 19 15:17:05 natalyp5e org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3658]: ** (process:4000): WARNING **: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/  enumerator/1 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
Feb 19 16:17:01 natalyp5e CRON[11220]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 19 16:39:47 natalyp5e kernel: [27369.442324] perf: interrupt took too long (330265 > 266107), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 500
Feb 19 16:53:29 natalyp5e kernel: [28191.683215] INFO: NMI handler (perf_event_nmi_handler) took too long to run: 27.798 msecs
Feb 19 16:53:55 natalyp5e kernel: [28217.552664] perf: interrupt took too long (476468 > 412831), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 250
Feb 19 17:17:01 natalyp5e CRON[12348]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 19 17:39:08 natalyp5e kernel: [30931.228242] INFO: NMI handler (perf_event_nmi_handler) took too long to run: 27.841 msecs
Feb 19 17:40:07 natalyp5e kernel: [30990.344084] perf: interrupt took too long (628260 > 595585), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 250
Feb 19 17:45:15 natalyp5e kernel: [31297.717526] INFO: NMI handler (perf_event_nmi_handler) took too long to run: 28.060 msecs
Feb 19 18:06:01 natalyp5e CRON[13231]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
Feb 19 18:15:12 natalyp5e kernel: [33095.339710] perf: interrupt took too long (835029 > 785325), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 250
Feb 19 18:17:08 natalyp5e CRON[13435]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_avail() returned a value that is exceptionally large: 946720 bytes (5366 ms).
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the   ALSA developers.
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 4408
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 1102
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 24988
Feb 19 18:17:58 natalyp5e pulseaudio[3830]: [alsa-sink-AD1988B Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
```

Sometimes when see films from the internet, it freezes.

How resolve these freezes?

only reisub can reset system mouse and keyboard don't response

additional logs

```
CRON[5392]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 26 20:36:49 natalyp5e kernel: [14030.350602] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mar 26 20:36:51 natalyp5e kernel: [14032.323650] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mar 26 20:36:53 natalyp5e kernel: [14034.269788] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mar 26 20:36:55 natalyp5e kernel: [14036.142185] sysrq: Emergency Sync
Mar 26 20:36:55 natalyp5e kernel: [14036.142261] Emergency Sync complete
Mar 26 20:36:56 natalyp5e kernel: [14037.742043] sysrq: Emergency Remount R/O
Mar 26 20:37:42 natalyp5e systemd-modules-load[273]: Inserted module 'lp'
Mar 26 20:37:42 natalyp5e systemd-modules-load[273]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Mar 26 20:37:42 natalyp5e systemd-modules-load[273]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Mar 26 20:37:42 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
```

i update to 20.04
and problem still exists
display-manager freezes. only service restart display-manager helps

this is logs  freeze occured about 9.51

```
Mar 31 09:31:01 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Mar 31 09:31:01 natalyp5e anacron[7344]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-03-31
Mar 31 09:31:01 natalyp5e anacron[7344]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Mar 31 09:31:01 natalyp5e systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:35:06 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Mar 31 09:35:06 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.]
Mar 31 09:35:06 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 7780 of process 7709 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Mar 31 09:35:06 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Mar 31 09:35:14 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: message repeated 22 times: [ Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.]
Mar 31 09:35:14 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 8104 of process 7902 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Mar 31 09:35:14 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Mar 31 09:36:04 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: message repeated 6 times: [ Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.]
Mar 31 09:36:04 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 8393 of process 7806 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Mar 31 09:36:04 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 6 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Mar 31 09:46:41 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[752]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.155' (uid=1000 pid=7709 comm="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:46:41 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Mar 31 09:46:41 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[752]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Mar 31 09:46:41 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Mar 31 09:47:11 natalyp5e systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:49:45 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started Session 5 of user nataly.
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopping Light Display Manager...
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopping Session c2 of user nataly.
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e pulseaudio[1312]: ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 1312, errno = 11
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e kernel: [ 4115.898784] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 01007aa000 on channel -1 [0fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: Stopped Sound Service.
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: Starting Sound Service...
Mar 31 09:51:15 natalyp5e pulseaudio[9789]: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Mar 31 09:51:16 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Mar 31 09:51:16 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: message repeated 9 times: [ Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.]
Mar 31 09:51:16 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[752]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.181' (uid=1000 pid=9789 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:51:16 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Mar 31 09:51:16 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: Started Sound Service.
Mar 31 09:51:17 natalyp5e indicator-sound[1528]: volume-control-pulse.vala:744: Unable to connect to dbus server at 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/pulse/dbus-socket': Could not connect: No such file or directory
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e scp-dbus-servic[6180]: system-config-printer: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e kernel: [ 4130.257806] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0100927000 on channel -1 [0fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e at-spi-bus-launcher[1427]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e [1590]: xfce4-notifyd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e [1432]: xfce4-screensaver: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e kernel: [ 4130.321610] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0100aa4000 on channel -1 [0fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopped Session c2 of user nataly.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: gpu-manager.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Finished Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Mar 31 09:51:29 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 108.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/108...
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/108.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 108...
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Reached target Paths.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Reached target Timers.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on Sound System.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Reached target Sockets.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Reached target Basic System.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 108.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Starting Sound Service...
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user lightdm.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 9895 of process 9895 owned by '108' high priority at nice level -11.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 2 users.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Mar 31 09:51:30 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[9904]: [session uid=108 pid=9904] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[9904]: [session uid=108 pid=9904] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=108 pid=9902 comm="/usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[9904]: [session uid=108 pid=9904] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Started Accessibility services bus.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[9904]: [session uid=108 pid=9904] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service' requested by ':1.4' (uid=108 pid=9902 comm="/usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[9904]: [session uid=108 pid=9904] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e at-spi-bus-launcher[9914]: dbus-daemon[9914]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=108 pid=9902 comm="/usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e at-spi-bus-launcher[9914]: dbus-daemon[9914]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e at-spi-bus-launcher[9945]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 2 users.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 9948 of process 9895 owned by '108' RT at priority 5.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 2 users.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 2 users.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 9949 of process 9895 owned by '108' RT at priority 5.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 2 users.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Started Sound Service.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Reached target Main User Target.
Mar 31 09:51:31 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Startup finished in 1.092s.
Mar 31 09:51:41 natalyp5e pulseaudio[9789]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Mar 31 09:51:41 natalyp5e pulseaudio[9895]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopping Session c3 of user lightdm.
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started Session c4 of user nataly.
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e systemd[1]: session-c3.scope: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopped Session c3 of user lightdm.
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e pulseaudio[9895]: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e at-spi-bus-launcher[1418]: dbus-daemon[1418]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=9988 comm="xfce4-session " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e at-spi-bus-launcher[1418]: dbus-daemon[1418]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e at-spi-bus-launcher[10091]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[1329]: [session uid=1000 pid=1329] Activating service name='org.xfce.ScreenSaver' requested by ':1.101' (uid=1000 pid=9988 comm="xfce4-session " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:52:07 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[1329]: [session uid=1000 pid=1329] Successfully activated service 'org.xfce.ScreenSaver'
Mar 31 09:52:08 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[1329]: [session uid=1000 pid=1329] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1' requested by ':1.126' (uid=1000 pid=10152 comm="xfdesktop " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[1329]: [session uid=1000 pid=1329] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' unit='xfce4-notifyd.service' requested by ':1.129' (uid=1000 pid=10169 comm="xfce4-volumed " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: Starting XFCE notifications service...
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[1329]: [session uid=1000 pid=1329] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: Started XFCE notifications service.
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[10165]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[10165]: Registered thumbnailer evince-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[10165]: Registered thumbnailer atril-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[10165]: Registered thumbnailer gnome-thumbnail-font --size %s %u %o
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[10165]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[1329]: [session uid=1000 pid=1329] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1'
Mar 31 09:52:09 natalyp5e NetworkManager[754]: <info>  [1617173529.7264] agent-manager: agent[440757c098a299f1,:1.209/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[752]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' unit='blueman-mechanism.service' requested by ':1.210' (uid=1000 pid=10175 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[752]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.213' (uid=1000 pid=10173 comm="/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --executed-" label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e blueman-mechanism[10309]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e blueman-mechanism[10309]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e blueman-mechani[10309]: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[752]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[1329]: [session uid=1000 pid=1329] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Applet' unit='blueman-applet.service' requested by ':1.164' (uid=1000 pid=10305 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-tray " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: Starting Bluetooth management applet...
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e dbus-daemon[1329]: [session uid=1000 pid=1329] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Applet'
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: Started Bluetooth management applet.
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e blueman-applet[10340]: blueman-applet version 2.1.2 starting
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e blueman-applet[10340]: There is an instance already running
Mar 31 09:52:10 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: blueman-applet.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 108...
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: run-user-108-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: run-user-108-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: run-user-108-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: dbus.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: at-spi-dbus-bus.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: gvfs-daemon.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopped target Paths.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopped target Sockets.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Stopped target Timers.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: dbus.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: dirmngr.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: gpg-agent-browser.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: gpg-agent-extra.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: gpg-agent-ssh.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: gpg-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: pk-debconf-helper.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed Sound System.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: snapd.session-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Finished Exit the Session.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[9887]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: user@108.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 108.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/108...
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: run-user-108.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@108.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/108.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 108.
Mar 31 09:52:17 natalyp5e systemd[1306]: run-user-108.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:52:40 natalyp5e systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 09:53:10 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Mar 31 09:53:10 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.]
Mar 31 09:53:10 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 10577 of process 10506 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Mar 31 09:53:10 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Mar 31 09:53:18 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: message repeated 20 times: [ Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.]
Mar 31 09:53:18 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 10888 of process 10703 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Mar 31 09:53:18 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Mar 31 09:54:22 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: message repeated 6 times: [ Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.]
Mar 31 09:54:22 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 11239 of process 10682 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Mar 31 09:54:22 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 3 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Mar 31 09:54:22 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: message repeated 4 times: [ Supervising 3 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.]
Mar 31 09:54:22 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 11248 of process 10603 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Mar 31 09:54:22 natalyp5e rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 4 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
```

Comment: FYI: Xubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://xubuntu.org/release/16-04/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` on your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Xubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: I update it to 18.04 and freezezes still appear.    This is logs strange only i find in time where freeze came on / I edit question add  logs

Comment: Update first text  please see it I update to 20.04